# How can I add 2 open functions but delay one?

Tags: javascript

I need to make an app which uses the function tool to stamp a dog and then delay it to stamp an old man. Could you assist me with using the function tool for stamping 2 objects (not at the same time)? Thank you.

I've tried to use...

```
function open2() {
  // code here
}
```

and I've also tried to use...

```
function open() {
  // code here
}
```

for both of them

```
function open(){
  stamp ('dog14',600,850,200)
  sound ('dog')

  sound('old man')
  stamp('old man',300,700)
}
```

When I use that code the dog and the old man are stamped at the same time but I need the old man to be stamped 3 seconds after the dog.

Comment: Your question is bit unclear, try to add the code and expected output.

Comment: Isn't it cruel to stamp on dogs and old men?...

Comment: use the Promises to clear this kind of issues check he promises https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a homework question, so I'll hint you to a good answer. To introduce a delay, you can use a `setTimeout` or wrap one code in a promise.

The timeout example:

```js
function stamp (x) {
  console.log("Stamped " + x)
}

function sound (x) {
  console.log("Sounded " + x)
}

function open() {
  stamp ('dog14',600,850,200)
  sound ('dog')

  setTimeout(function () {
    sound('old man')
    stamp('old man',300,700)
  }, 3000) // executes after 3,000 milliseconds
}

open()
```

You might also want to use a promise. The difference here is that a promise will ensure your events are executed serially. If you used a timeout, the second bit of the code (stamping the old man) will happen whether or not the first part ran (stamping the dog). A promise will make sure the dog happens first, then the old man.

You can do it any number of ways. Here's one that you might want to explore.

```
function stampAndSoundDog () {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // stamp and sound dog here
    // then call resolve after a 3s timeout
  })
}

function open {
  stampAndSoundDog.then(function() {
    // stamp and sound the old man here
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function and include a timeout. Including **[Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)** is a simpler alternative for managing asynchronous operations. Below are **four 
functions:**

1. **stamp(figure)**
2. **sound(figure)**
3. **stampAndSound(figure)**

   - returns an **asynchronous operation**.

     - If `figure` is empty or undefined, the promise gets **rejected**. the `catch` method catches that and logs the what is returned. In this case, `'Nothing to stamp and sound'` is returned.
     - **otherwise**, `stamp` and `sound` gets called and the promise **resolves**
4. **open()**

```js
function stamp(figure){
  console.log(figure + ' stamped');
}

function sound(figure){
  console.log(figure + ' sounded');
}

function stampAndSound(figure) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // if empty argument is given, reject promise
    if(figure === undefined || figure == ''){ 
      reject('Nothing to stamp and sound');
    }else{
      // otherwise stamp and sound 
      stamp(figure);
      sound(figure);
      resolve();
    }
  })
}

// define variables ...
let oldMan = 'old man';
//let dog = '';  // uncomment this line and comment the one below to test how the promise rejects
let dog = 'pitbull';

function open(){
  // stampAndSound oldMan first then dog
  stampAndSound(oldMan).then(function() {
    // wait three seconds then stamp and sound dog
    setTimeout(function(){
      stampAndSound(dog).catch(function(error){ // if promise gets rejected.. 
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
      });
    }, 3000) 
  }).catch(function(error){ // if promise gets rejected.. 
    console.log('Error: ' + error);
  })
}

open();
```

## ES6 Syntax

```js
const stamp = (figure) => {  console.log(`${figure} stamped`); }

const sound = (figure) => { console.log(`${figure} sounded`); }

const stampAndSound = (figure) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(figure === undefined || figure == ''){ 
      reject('Nothing to stamp and sound');
    }else{
      stamp(figure);
      sound(figure);
      resolve();
    }
  })
}

// define variables ...
let oldMan = 'old man';
let dog = 'pitbull';

const open = () => {
  stampAndSound(oldMan).then(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      stampAndSound(dog).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
      });
    }, 3000); 
  }).catch((error) => { 
    console.log('Error: ' + error);
  })
}

open();
```